# Calculate Interval based on Identifiers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to write a PostgreSQL query that gives time differences based on other record data?

That is, I have something like:

```
ID | CAT | Realtime   | Value   
---+-----+------------+------
A  |   1 | timestamp1 |    10
A  |   1 | timestamp2 |    15
A  |   2 | timestamp1 |     2
A  |   2 | timestamp2 |    55
B  |   1 | timestamp1 |     5
B  |   1 | timestamp2 |    10
```

And I'd like to add a field that finds the difference between timestamp 2 - timestamp1 based on identifiers ID AND CAT.

Comment: How do you know that timestamp2 is after timestamp1? Which column can be used for sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but is this what you're looking for?

```
select id,cat,max(realtime)-min(realtime) as interval
from table
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: +1, very clever: whichever is smaller should indeed be the beginning and the other the end. And if they managed to store the smaller value as `timestamp2`, not `timestamp1` – well, we are not responsible for their silliness, are we. :)

Comment: Thank for the input. I'll be trying a version of this soon!

Comment: Basically, if I make make this extra silly, what I'm trying to do is the following excel forumla

=IF(AND(B3=B2, C3=C2,D3=D2), J3-J2,0)

So I have 3 columns that are identifiers, and one (my time) that I want to operate on. I'm new to Perl but am trying to use that. We'll see!